# Back swipe gesture is not work when I add the leftBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

Here is a `ViewControllerA` push a `ViewControllerB`, and in the `ViewControllerB` the `leftBarButtonItem` is set as following:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:)];
```

After setting the `leftBarButtonItem`, the Back swipe gesture is not work. Is it possible to keep the swipe gesture?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because you've changed the left bar button item, you're telling the navigation controller to stop managing the navigation-based back-actions that the user can take.

To fix it, you can tell the navigation controller to continue accepting those gestures on the current view controller by using:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Where `self` if your view controller.

`UIViewController` privately implements `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, so you'll get a warning for this, but you can mitigate this by adding in the protocol conformance (`<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`) to your header, or to a class extension.

Comment: I've heard theres issues with this, but it appears to work at first glance. anyone run into weird issues using this?

Comment: I found one reference to potential issues: Specifically the issue would be, if you try to swipe while another pop animation is already happening, it will cause the exception where you can't do multiple transitions at once. The proposed solution is to make a custom UINavigationController where the navigation controller itself is the interactionPopGestureRecognizer delegate, and it will ignore swipes while another navigation transition is in progress.

I prefer UINavigationBar setBackIndicatorImage to set a custom image for the back button.

Answer (score 1):

try to set interactivePopGestureRecognizer to nil

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = nil;

}
```